# Wasted space in linked list and array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list, complexity-theory

In a book there is a comparison between linked list, array and dynamic array. The parameter name is wasted space.Values given are:

- array 0
- linked list O(n)
- dynamic array O(n)

What is the wasted space parameter and why it is O(n) for a linked list and 0 for array?

Comment: Better fit for https://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose *wasted space* is an amount of space allocated by the data structure minus the amount of space needed to store its elements.

**Array**. Usually, arrays contain nothing besides its elements. Sometimes they store their size or additional memory is needed for memory alignment purposes. I'd say it would be correct to claim that 'wasted space' for an array is `O(1)`.

**Linked list**. We need at least one pointer for each element of the list. Thus, we have `O(n)` 'wasted space'.

**Dynamic array**. We need an additional `O(n)` memory when we have not enough space to store all elements when increasing size of a dynamic array. We need to allocate a new memory buffer and then copy elements to this buffer. Moreover, usually dynamic arrays resize by a large amount of additional memory (to get amortized `O(1)` add/remove operations). And the size of wasted memory is  `O(n)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let n be the amount of data in the dynamic array, capacity be the amount of memory available. Then n <= capacity && n >= capacity/4, and the average amount of wasted space is n*3/2 ~ O(n).